# Should I clean up my socket.on's on the server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Should I clean up socket listeners on the server or does it not matter?

For example:

```
 io.on('connection', socket => {
  const addMessageListener = (message, callback) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', message)
    callback(message)
  }

  socket.on('message', addMessageListener)

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.off('message', addMessageListener)
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The socket itself handles people disconnecting
But it is better to just announce that someone left (if necessary)

example userX was offline

example userX left the groups

```
socket.broadcast.emit("onlineUser", socket.id);
```

or

```
socket.to("room1").emit(/* ... */);
```

or

```
io.of("myNamespace").emit(/* ... */);
```